# Selenium IDE Dynamic ID created by website

Tags: html, css, selenium, ide

I started to work with Selenium IDE 2.9.1 as a plugin connected to Firefox. What I want is to store dynamic created id of a new document and open it at the end. For example:

- I created a document, DataBase gave automatic ID: dp_137282
- after this there is a Selenium code that doing something else, it is not important,
- But at the end Selenium should find my document by ID and open it using double click command.

Please check code below:

```
<div id="content" style="height: 373px; width: 1324px;">
<div class="main-content" rel="kancelaria/rkp/rkp-faktury/type//rok_roboczy/2017">
<h3 class="gray">
<form class="form" action="kancelaria/rkp/rkp-faktury/type//rok_roboczy/2017" onsubmit="">
<input style="display:none;" value="asd" type="submit">
<div id="flex-list">
<table id="kancelaria-rkp-index" class="dark-gray overlap" style="width:100%;" headlines="">
<thead>
<tr id="dp_137282" class="multi-selectable" style="" ondblclick="this.className += ' doubleclicked'; Load.Content('kancelaria/rkp/szczegoly-rkp-faktury/id/dp_137282')" data-b="kancelaria/rkp/szczegoly-rkp-faktury/id/dp_137282" onclick="" data-status="">
```

[Please click here to view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln7vS.jpg)

At the end I used xpath in Target field

```
xpath=(//td[@onclick=' '])[7]
```

I found that always new document created by Selenium is on the top so this should not be a problem to open it, but I don't want to relay on this. So if someone of you know resolve and can share I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `storeAttribute` command to store your ID attribute of `<td>` tag  and later you can use it

e.g.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>xpath=//table[@id='kancelaria-rkp-index']/thead/tr/@id</td>
    <td>dynamicvalue</td>
</tr>
```

This will store your dynamic id

and after all finished you can utilize that id e.g.

```
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${dynamicvalue}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

To print the `id` attribute value

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=${dynamicvalue}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

To click on element whose id has stored